# Data Structure that supports constant time for addbegin, addend and random access

Tags: data-structures

I am looking for a data structure that supports constant time performance for adding an element to the beginning, end, and random access.

I am thinking double ended queue. Does double ended queue support constant time performance for random access? If so, how does it achieve it?

I know one can use double linked list to build a double ended queue. But How do you build an index on all the elements to achieve constant time random access?

Thank you for your help.

Jerry

Comment: Most deques I know of are doubly linked lists of medium-sized arrays, so those won't give you random access in armotized O(1). OTOH I imagine an array with armotized O(1) append and prepend is possible...

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for would be a double-ended queue by definition, but that's just an abstract data structure. Wikipedia discusses [several implementation strategies for deques](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-ended_queue#Implementations) in terms of dynamic arrays; using these, you can get amortized O(1) prepend and append. The circular buffer strategy seems the easiest to implement, at first glance.

Comment: C++ STL library provides deque class that supports random access. I am wondering how that is implemented and the performance of that operation.

Comment: @JerryXu: check the file `bits/stl_deque.h` in the GNU C++ headers; vgrep for the comments in `/** */`.